# If statement, not carrying much for true or false in Android Activity

Tags: android, if-statement, countdowntimer

I'm defending my Bachelor tomorrow. There is some issues in my code. I'm creating a countdowntimer at specific times & it should also not be creating multiple timers because I'm using an if statemet:

```
if (norm[j] / 9.5 < normT) {

                            if (!isRunning){ // Only starting 1 timer at a time
                                Log.d(TAG,"Checking Velocities"); // Debugging
                                final counterClass timer = new counterClass(3000, 10, norm, diff);
                                timer.start();
                            }
```

The above is part of the function which instantiate a timer. This isRunning boolean should only be false when the counter has finished:

```
public class counterClass extends CountDownTimer {

    double[] nor = new double[120];
    double[] dif = new double[119];

    public counterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, double[] norm, double[] diff) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval); // Duration & how often onTick should be called
        isRunning = true;
        nor = norm;
        dif = diff;


    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //listFall(); // Adding accelerometer data to fall list array List each time its called
      vCheck(nor,dif); // Calculate velocity approximation every 10th millisecond.
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
      isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

These are the only times I'm using the boolean, other than when I'm declaring it, in the mainactivity class. When I look at the Log.d output it will keep outputting "Checking Velocities" when certain criteria has been met. And this is what's very confusing to me.

The norm[j]/9.5 < normT is called from here:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){ // Checking Accelerometer changes

    // Storing values in double variables.
     x = event.values[0];
     y = event.values[1];
     z = event.values[2];

    if(xList.size() < 120) // Fill array list for calculations.
    {
        xList.add(x);
        yList.add(y);
        zList.add(z);
    }
    else {
        sample(); // Run the norm calculations.
        removeVList(); // Remove first index, and move all other indexes a step back, making room for a new input.


    }
```

Comment: Your class should start with Cap letters. counterClass-> CounterClass.
is isRunning static ?

Comment: No it's just a private boolean. Is that the issue? - I've changed counter to cap letter.

Comment: Where is the first block of code located, what is `isRunning`?

Comment: from where are you calling  if (norm[j] / 9.5 < normT)

Comment: I'm calling if(norm[j] etc..) from a function called private void sample(). This function is run when accelerometer data from x, y, z axis has filled 3 arraylists with 120 samples each. I'm also removing 1 of the inputs in the array, after sample(); has run, to fill in another set of values in order to keep checking for velocities and such.

Comment: I'll add the block of code from where it's called in my question.

Comment: @RC it is located in the beginning of my ActivityMain.Class, and it is a private boolean.